# Embedding python plugins in multithreaded C application

Tags: python, c, plugins, pthreads, cpython

A friend and I are trying to implement a python plugin service for one of our C applications. Ideally we would like for the plugins to run in their own thread. So far we have a plugin class that the user implements, a running plugin is just an instance of the user implemented class. We need the running plugin instances to be able receive messages from another thread.

We have what almost appears to be a working solution but are running into issues with the GIL. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to go about implementing this?

Thanks